# Result is different when use base64_decode with php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have some problem with `base64` encode and decode, I would like to decode my string with php, I have found a solution but it's not work well, My expectation I would like decode only string which have been encode and other string which is not encoded should keep normal.

Here is a string :

```
$string  = "I need your help 4Z6B4Z+S4Z6b4Z624Z+G4Z6E4oCL4Z6O4Z624Z6f4Z+L4oCL";
```

Here is what I have tried :

```
echo base64_decode($string);
```

Result:

```
SSBuZWVkIHlvdXIgaGVscA = ខ្លាំង​ណាស់​
```

The result above is not what I need, below is what I need:

```
I need your help ខ្លាំង​ណាស់​
```

So, could anyone tell me how to do it with php.

Comment: `base64_decode` expects a string that is base64 encoded. You need to first separate the base64 parts from the other text parts, do `base64_decode` on them, then merge them back into one string.

Comment: The other issue is that, how do you treat a string like `"ROFL"`. It could be interpreted as both a normal text, or a base64 encoded string (that decodes to a 3-byte string).

Comment: could you tell me how could check if string has been encode ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $str = "I need your help 4Z6B4Z+S4Z6b4Z624Z+G4Z6E4oCL4Z6O4Z624Z6f4Z+L4oCL";


    for($count = 0; $count < strlen($str); $count++) {

        $temp = substr($str, $count, strlen($str));
        if ( base64_encode(base64_decode($temp, true)) === $temp) {
            echo substr($str, 0, $count) . base64_decode($str);
            break;
        }

    }

?>
```